# Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't using CommonModule?

Tags: angular

I get this message:

```
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

So, all components that I use were declared in shareModule.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],

      declarations: [
        BlockComponent,
        FieldComponent],

exports: [
 BlockComponent,
        FieldComponent
]

});
```

So, when `BlockComponent` is rendered this error message appears. Why if I imported `CommonModule`

But sometimes it works, sometimes not...

Angular 10.

Main component `app-document-form-node` that reused in recursion is:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="block.type === fielType.Block">
    <app-block [block]="block" [parent]="parent" [show]="true"></app-block>
</ng-container>
```

`BlockComponent` is:

```
<div class="document-block">
    <div class="document-block__title" (click)="toggle()" *ngIf="block.title">
        {{ block.title }}
        <span class="pull-right" (click)="remove($event)" *ngIf="block?.remove"><i class="fa fa-times fa-sm pr-1"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="document-block__body" *ngIf="show">
        <ng-container *ngIf="block.tag === 'ADRESATS'">
            <app-adresat-list [parent]="block" [adresats]="block.children">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="children; context: { block: block }"> </ng-container>
            </app-adresat-list>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container *ngIf="block.tag === 'ADRESAT'">
            <app-adresat [block]="block">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="children; context: { block: block }"> </ng-container>
            </app-adresat>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container *ngIf="block.tag === 'WORD_SETTINGS'">
            <app-word-settings [element]="block">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="children; context: { block: block }"> </ng-container>
            </app-word-settings>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container *ngIf="block.tag === 'PARAMETERS'">
            <app-parameters [element]="block">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="children; context: { block: block }"> </ng-container>
            </app-parameters>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container *ngIf="block.tag === 'GENERICPARAMETERS'">
            <app-document-parameters [element]="block">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="children; context: { block: block }"> </ng-container>
            </app-document-parameters>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-template #children let-block="block">
    <ng-container *ngIf="block?.children">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let child of block.children">
            <app-document-form-node [parent]="block" [block]="child"></app-document-form-node>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

As you can see main block is reused recursive if children exist in template above:

```
<ng-template #children let-block="block">
```

I have found line where it is failed:

```
<div class="document-block__body" *ngIf="show">
```

Comment: How to get in which component this happened and line? No it is just a common error: `core.js:7824 Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`

Comment: for angular directives like ngif, you have to import CommonModule (see https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule)

Comment: See my question, I have said that I use this import

Comment: Can you please add code of template as well ? I hope you are using *ngIf inside template

Comment: Yes, I can post, one minute

Comment: You can see updated question

Comment: Problem is SOMETIME after npm stop npm start ir works

Comment: Ans sometimes I got error for main component: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'DocumentFormNodeComponent' before initialization`

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you import commonModule on app.module.ts? If so, you imported the commonModule in sharedModule.ts file, in that case you don’t want to import it again in . app.module.ts. @Mamkad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wrote "ngIf" instead of "*ngIf"? This is a common mistake. Another possible problem is that your imports are above your declarations. That's an order I never tried before.

Comment: Could be reason: `WARNING in Circular dependency detected:`?

Comment: What do you mean `Another possible problem is that your imports are above your declarations. `?

Comment: I have checked all component everywhere is `*ngIf`

Comment: What I mean is, you have imports, then declarations. The usual order is having declarations, then imports, then exports. It's unlikely that this is the problem, but it's worth trying. Also you can try adding CommonModule to exports, since it doesn't hurt to do it. A third solution might be to change the order of items in your imports array. If you import some module that relies on CommonModule before you import CommonModule, there will be an error. A fourth solution might be to stop ng serve and restart VSC.